# AndroidViewClient - can't getXY() coordinates

Tags: android, python, android-uiautomator, androidviewclient

I'm running AndroidViewClient and am able to dump a complete hierarchy, but things fail when I try to getXY() or touch(). Even the solution from [Get Current Focused Window Name using AndroidViewClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089937/get-current-focused-window-name-using-androidviewclient) gives me an error.

```
  kwargs1 = {'verbose': True, 'ignoresecuredevice': True}
  kwargs2 = {'startviewserver': True, 'forceviewserveruse': True,
             'autodump': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True}
  device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
  vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)
  view = vc.dump(window='-1')
  widget = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/5")
  widget.useUiAutomator = False
  print widget
  # Up until here runs no problem.
  print widget.getXY() # fails.
  widget.touch() # also fails.
```

My stack trace goes something like:

print widget.getXY()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-11.5.3-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 680, in getXY
    (wvx, wvy) = self.__dumpWindowsInformation(debug=debug)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-11.5.3-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 798, in __dumpWindowsInformation

```
dww = self.device.shell('dumpsys window windows')
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-11.5.3-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py", line 377, in shell

```
self.__send('shell:%s' % cmd, checkok=True, reconnect=False)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-11.5.3-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py", line 243, in __send

```
self.__checkOk()
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-11.5.3-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py", line 286, in __checkOk

```
raise RuntimeError("ERROR: %s %s" % (repr(recv), error))
```

RuntimeError: ERROR: ''

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the device and it's API level?

Comment: Nexus 5X emulator, API level 23

Comment: Why are you forcing ViewServer use (`'forceviewserveruse': True`)? API 23 should use `uiautomator`.

Comment: Aah, because elsewhere in the program, I am also getting the window name and I reach an error: Exception: Not implemented yet: listing windows with UiAutomator. But I can get around that :)

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Could you explain why this is tagged as android-uiautomator? This question is highly specific to AndroidViewClient and doesn't seem relevant to users of the UI Automator library (even though AndroidViewClient is built on top).

Comment: @AllenHair it is related to UiAutomator because it's a problem that only happens if UiAutomator is not used as a back-end.

Answer (score 0):

```
widget = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/5")
widget.useUiAutomator = False
widget.getXY() 
x = (str)widget.windows[widget.currentFocus] 
print x
```

Above code will get the Display Activity name and height and width of the screen,if u want only height and width refer below one

```
h = device._AdbClient__getDisplayHeight("")
w = device._AdbClient__getDisplayWidth("")
print (str)(h)
print (str)(w)
```